# How to show a physical (relief) map with the Google Maps API for Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

In the Google Maps JavaScript API V2 there is a constant named:
G_PHYSICAL_MAP. It is a map type which displays maps with physical
features such as terrain and vegetation.
I'm looking for something similar in the Google Maps API for Android.
Thanks
José

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no terrain layer in the Google Maps API as of API Level 9.